# Java Object Serialization java.io.UTFDataFormatException

Tags: java, exception, serialization, encryption

i have an Object, i want to serialize into byte code:

```
public class objektserial implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String msg ="";
private LinkedList<String> stringlist = new LinkedList<String>();

public objektserial(String nachricht) {
this.msg = nachricht;
this.stringlist = new LinkedList<String>();
}

public objektserial(){      
}

public String getMsg(){
return msg;
}

public void setList(LinkedList<String> list){
this.stringlist = list;
}
}
```

My Idea:
1. Serialize it
2. encrypt the ByteCode 
3. encrypt the ByteCode
4. Deserialize it

```
   // Serialization
objektserial os = new objektserial(textField.getText());
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    list.add("String Nr. " + i);
os.setList(list);

try {
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("objekt.objs");
    ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
    o.writeObject(os);
    o.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(e);
}

// Encrypt
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("objekt.objs"));
    String s = "";
    String text = "";
    while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
        text += s;
    }
    String passwordEnc = AESencrp.encrypt(text);
    String passwordDec = AESencrp.decrypt(passwordEnc);
    File file = new File("objekt.objs");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, false);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    writer.write(passwordEnc);

    writer.close();

    System.out.println("Plain Text : " + text);
    System.out.println("Encrypted Text : " + passwordEnc);
    System.out.println("Decrypted Text : " + passwordDec);
    } catch (Exception eiasdasd) {
    }

// Decrypt
try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("objekt.objs"));
    String s = "";
    String text = "";
    while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
        text += s;
    }
    String passwordDec = AESencrp.decrypt(text);
    File file = new File("objekt.objs");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, false);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    writer.write(passwordDec);

    writer.close();

    System.out.println("Plain Text : " + text);
    System.out.println("Encrypted Text : " + text);
    System.out.println("Decrypted Text : " + passwordDec);
} catch (Exception eiasdasd) {
}

// Read&Dezerialize
try {
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("objekt.objs");
ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(file);
objektserial obs = (objektserial) o.readObject();
o.close();
textField_1.setText(obs.getMsg());
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

That works fine, but if my Serialized Object is too big (more than one line, if i open the bytecode file with Notepad++), I get a `"java.io.UTFDataFormatException"`.

I get the `java.io.UTFDataFormatException` when I try to Deserialize & Read the decrypted File again...

**What can I do to fix this?**

Comment: There are many many things wrong with the above code. You are reading and writing to the same file, you don't need an intermediate file. You are treating binary (byte arrays) as String values and vice versa. I don't see any decryption method. Fixing indentation and keeping to Java style guides would be a lot of help too. My advice is to start over and create separate parts to do the file writing, the encoding/decoding, character encoding decoding and  encryption/decryption *and test them separately*.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing with ObjectStream.writeObject(). You need to read with ObjectInputStream.readObject().

Serialized objects are not lines. They are also not character data, which rules out Readers.

Comment: I am reading with ObjectInputstream (see last Methode).
I am reading the lines just for encrypting and decrypting.

But the problem is solved:
-just had to add at encrypt and at decrypt +"\n"

 while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
        text += s+"\n";
    }

Now it works perfect, even with bigger Objects! :)

Comment: You are reading with, and I quote, `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("objekt.objs");`. This is not valid for the reasons I have already given. You need to read and encrypt *bytes.*

Comment: @owlstead Encrypt. He has a post-process that reads the file and encrypts it. Read the question please. It could have been part of the original process, with a CipherOutputStream. He also needs to write the ciphertext as bytes not Strings.